# variables losing value when def is entered python

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm writing a simple calculator program, and a price variable is initially set. However, when i enter a function it clears my variable data, saying that the variable is undefined even though it's clearly been defined earlier in the program.

```
n = int(input("How many tickets would you like?"))
cls()
if n >= 10:
    print("Your group is large enough for our group discount!")
    price = n * 5
else:
    price = n * 6
def vet():
    vet = input("Are you a veteran of any branch of the United States 
    Military?")

    if vet.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        print("Thank you for your service. Your discount has been applied.")
        price *= 0.90
```

There's more code after and before this of course,but it seems as though entering this function is what causes my variable value to clear.
  I feel as though there's an obvious answer I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Variables are [local to the scope of the function that they're defined in](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html), with a handful of exceptions. You should pass your price into the vet function as an argument (which shouldn't be named the same as a variable just as a general rule, although it works in this case) and then have the vet function return the new price.

Comment: Try changing the name of either the `vet` function or the `vet` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so that my comment above is clear, this is the way to handle the problem you've encountered. It explicitly passes in the price and then returns it, instead of relying on an out-of-scope variable.

```
n = int(input("How many tickets would you like?"))
cls()
if n >= 10:
    print("Your group is large enough for our group discount!")
    price = n * 5
else:
    price = n * 6

def ask_vet(price):
    is_vet = input("Are you a veteran of any branch of the United States Military?")
    if is_vet.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        print("Thank you for your service. Your discount has been applied.")
        price *= 0.90
    return price
price = ask_vet(price)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you declare price as a global variable it will work. Let me know if you have any trouble.

```
n = int(input("How many tickets would you like? "))
if n >= 10:
    print("Your group is large enough for our group discount!")
    price = n * 5
else:
    price = n * 6
def vet():
    global price
    vet = input("Are you a veteran of any branch of the United States 
    Military? ")

    if vet.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        print("Thank you for your service. Your discount has been applied.")
        price *= 0.90
```

Comment: It worked, but I've been told using global variables is generally frowned upon

Comment: They have their place in every language. But they can cause issues down the line.